# Find the solution(s) of the equation

Tags: monotone-functions

Find the solution(s) of the following equation:

${\ln(2-x)}+1=2-e^{x-1}$,

$x=1$ is a solution of the equation but I cannot show that it is the only solution. I find it diffucult to show that function $f(x)={\ln(2-x)}+e^{x-1}-{1}$ is monotonic.

Comment: Try plotting the two sides of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This question is being downvoted (and will probably be closed) since you show no work of your own trying to answer it. In fact this equation does not have a closed form solution. The best you can do is find a numerical approximation. Draw the graph, then use guess-and-check.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I think that "$x=1$" is a fairly decent closed form.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Fair point. I didn't look carefully. Yes, it's closed form, but only because you can guess it. It's not an answer you can arrive at by "solving" using elementary functions. In the meanwhile, the OP has edited the question ...

Comment: @Ethan: this is clearly an exercise where there is an obvious solution, and the rest of the exercise is to show that there are no other roots. As shown by the tag "monotone-functons" and now explicitly by OP's edit.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your function is only defined for $x<2$. What you want to show is that the derivative
$$
f'(x)=-\frac1{2-x}+e^{x-1}
$$
is never zero. It is actually zero at $x=1$, but we can show that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x<2$ other than $x=1$. That is, we want to confirm that
$$
e^{x-1}\leq\frac1{2-x},\qquad x<2.
$$
Since $2-x>0$, this inequaliy is equivalent with
$$
(2-x)e^{x-1}\leq1.
$$
So we can look at this function $g(x)=(2-x)e^{x-1}$. We have
$$
g'(x)=-(x-1)e^{x-1}. 
$$
So $g'(x)=0$ implies $x=1$. Also,
$$
g''(x)=-xe^{x-1},
$$
so $g''(1)=-e^{-1}<0$. This shows that $x=1$ is the only local maximum for $g$. As $g$ is differentiable everywhere and it goes to $0$ at $-\infty$ and to $-\infty$ at $+\infty$, the maximum at $x=1$ is absolute. That is,
$$
(2-x)e^{x-1}=g(x)\leq g(1)=1.
$$
And, as this is the only local maximum and $g$ is differentiable everywhere, we get that $g(x)<1$ for all $x\ne1$. That is,
$$
(2-x)e^{x-1}<1,\qquad x<2\ \text{ and } x\ne1,
$$
which in turn is
$$
f'(x)<0,\qquad x<2\ \text{ and }x\ne1. 
$$

Comment: Do you think a proof without the use of derivatives is possible;

Comment: If you want to avoid derivatives, what properties of the exponential do you plan to use? How do you define the exponential and the logarithm?